# C# : Get memory usage after the external process exits

Tags: c#, memory, process

I want to get memory usage of a child process after it exited.

When I tried to get `PeakWorkingSet64` from a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object, it threw an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException:The process has exited, so the requested information cannot be obtained

My program has strict requirements on accuracy and efficiency, so polling is not a good choice.

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: By the way, is `PeakWorkingSet64` the infomation I truly want? --I want get the sum of all memory  used -- it's static memory + stack memory + heap memory + ...

Comment: The property contains peak value of physical memory allocated to the process. You cannot obtain this kind of information after a process has terminated.

Comment: You will have to do polling, unless you have some means of being notified when the program is about to terminate, or better yet, build the monitoring into the application itself so that it can read and report the values at the right time.